# Codingbat Warm-up exercise array123

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm new to programming and trying to wrap my head around this solution from codingbat.com.

> Given an array of ints, return True if the sequence of numbers 1, 2, 3 appears in the array somewhere.

This is the solution:

```
def array123(nums):
  # Note: iterate with length-2, so can use i+1 and i+2 in the loop
  for i in range(len(nums)-2):
    if nums[i]==1 and nums[i+1]==2 and nums[i+2]==3:
      return True
  return False
```

But why is (len(nums)-2) used? Does it have to do with where we start the for-in loop?

I can't seem to find the answer online I hope someone can help.

Comment: Do you understand what `range()` does?

Comment: It's not to do with where the loop starts. It's to do where the loop **ends**.

Comment: I understand what range does, sorry I'm having trouble understand why I would want it to end at -2 as in:   

array123([1, 1, 2, 3, 1])  Then it would run though the loop stopping at 3 (i.e. -2)?

Comment: Right, but what if you removed that `-2`, what would the range end at then? Note that *in the loop*, the code **adds** 2 to `i`.

Comment: Oh so it would end up adding to more than the available digits and would not have data to process!

Comment: Thank you I understand finally! :D

Comment: Exactly, it would try to index past the end of the list, so you'd get a `IndexError`. If your input list has 10 elements, you can only use indices 0 through to 9. If the `range()` produced all numbers up to `9`, you'd end up trying to access indices 10 and 11, which don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The loop ends at `len(nums)-2` because the *three* integers can not start past the *last three* items in the array. So for the last two array items is not necessary to check if there is a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution in which you don't have to worry about the `len(nums)-2` issue:

```
def array123(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i:i+3]==[1,2,3]:
            return True
    return False
```